# jQuery- How to append (-) in input

Tags: jquery

I want to create an input for activation code.My value like xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
and don't like to use multiple input for solution.

This mean,when it's value length inserted equal 4,it will automatically append a(-)between them.

Then, If user paste code xxxxxxxxxxxx, it will automatically change into xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

So, how conditions that I have to implement to do it in single input because many time I have attempted through logically,but failed to create a working and professional one.

html:

```
<input type="text" class="activation_code"/>
```

//the below is not practice way and professional,so how the better way to do that.Thanks :)

```
$('.activation_code').keyup(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
      if(value.length == 4){
         $(this).val(value+'-');
      }
      if(value.length == 9){
         $(this).val(value+'-');            
      }    
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use any **input-mask** plugin?

Comment: What don't you like about the multi-input? I would suggest multi-input where it automatically moves to the next one. You will have a nightmare trying to get it to work exactly right if you do it as one input. You have to consider backspaces, deletes and mid-text inputs otherwise. [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/kmx05pfz/)

Comment: I'm already create a working multi-input before,but just want to try a single input for this time..hehe.

Comment: This kind to improve my skill also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways to do it:

```js
$('.activation_code').keyup(function() {
  var input = $(this).val().split("-").join("");
  if (input.length > 0) {
    input = input.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}', 'g')).join("-");
  }
  $(this).val(input);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="activation_code" />
```

I strongly suggest server-sided validation if you haven't got this already. Never trust user input.

Comment: Oh,thank a lot,I have tested and working nice,even paste code into changed as my wishes..

Comment: Yup,I have already done server-sided validation,just to improve this one in front-end layout..Thanks yaa..

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it. You can specify the groupsize (the number of characters after which you want your `-`), and also the "divider" char that you want inserted.

```js
function convertTheInput(value, groupSize, dividerChar) {
  groupSize = groupSize || 4;
  dividerChar = dividerChar || "-";
  var newValue = "";
  value = value.split(dividerChar).join("");
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    if (i % groupSize === 0 && i > 0) {
      newValue += dividerChar;
    }
    newValue += value[i];
  }
  return newValue;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#theInput").on("keyup", function() {
    $(this).val(convertTheInput($(this).val(), 4, "-"));
  });
  $("#theInput2").on("keypress", function() {
    $(this).val(convertTheInput($(this).val(), 3, " "));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="theInput" /> keyup, groupsize 4, "-" <br />
<input type="text" id="theInput2" /> keypress, groupsize 3, " "
```

https://jsfiddle.net/es2qpkzc/6/

Comment: It's working on this page, and also in the fiddle. Please reload this page as I had numerous edits on the answer. It's now even reusable with configurable groupsize and delimiter character or string.

Comment: Owh,okay,it just working in typing and not for copy paste,anyway I have learned also something from your method,thanks for this..:)

Comment: The problem with using the `keyup` event it that it does no longer allow you to click in the field and mark all content by pressing CTRL A. That's why I used `keypress`. Just exchange the event back for `keyup` to make it support pasting.

Comment: I have now added a second usage example. First input uses `keyup`, second `keypress`. Just so you can fiddle around to find your perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

This way supports `paste` text on the input:

```
$(function(){
var test = $("#test");
  test.keyup(function(){
    var texto = $(this).val().split('-').join('');
    $(this).val(texto.match(/.{1,4}/g).join('-'));
  });
  test.on('paste',function(){
    var element = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        var texto = $(element).val();
        $(element).val(texto.match(/.{1,4}/g).join('-'));
      }, 100);      
  });
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/z8zbg2fj/

Comment: Thanks,its also working as above.So,I'm able to learn many way :D

Comment: I'm glad to help @smile